# Deploying WPF app with SQL Server Express database for Windows guest user

Tags: database, wpf, permissions, sql-server-express, setup-deployment

I'm trying to create a database when deploying my WPF application. I don't have any problem if the user of Windows is the admin user. But if the user uses Windows as a guest, the system doesn't allow me to create the database. I get a "permission denied" error.

Is there any way to get this permission when deploying the application or should the admin user give this permission manually before deploying?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A guest account can only create files in it's own user folders.
Meaning they'd have to create the database in appdata or on their desktop ( which sounds like a bad idea ).
I'm not sure they'd even be able to install sql server express. Never tried to on a guest account.

Whether that's  practical or not depends on what you're doing in what context.
Sql server express is a service based dbms with the service running in it's own context.  You could maybe install sql server and a database on the machine for them and they connect to that.

If this is just a fairly simple application which grabs a small amount of input then maybe serialisation would be a better approach than a database.

Comment: On the guest account, it allows installing SQL server express and SQL server management studio as well. But I couldn't create a database from SSMS too. It still needs permission. So you are only allowed to read data not to write on the guest account as default.